# Polling using kotlin coroutine with custom scope and view lifecycle

Tags: android, kotlin, coroutine, kotlin-coroutines

I am just starting with `Kotlin` coroutines. I am trying to poll the server using coroutine and want to stop polling when `Activity` or `Fragment` is paused and resume polling accordingly. So my `pollScope` has a shorter lifecycle than the one provided by `ViewModel.viewModelScope`. I am not fully satisfied with the implementation that I currently have, a few questions:

1. Is this the right way to create `pollScope`. I want it to cancel when `viewModelScope` is canceled as well so that's why I am specifying parent job.
2. Why coroutine doesn't start in `onResume()` if I cancel `pollJobs` using `coroutineContext.cancel()`? They start fine if I keep a list of jobs and cancel them.
3. Is this the overall right approach? Is there a better way?

```
    import androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner
    import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
    import androidx.lifecycle.viewModelScope
    import com.spruce.messenger.utils.FullLifecycleObserverAdapter
    import kotlinx.coroutines.*
    import java.io.IOException
    import java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList
    import kotlin.coroutines.CoroutineContext


    suspend fun poll(initialDelay: Long = 5000,
                     maxDelay: Long = 30000,
                     factor: Double = 2.0,
                     block: suspend () -> Unit) {

        var currentDelay = initialDelay
        while (true) {
            try {
                try {
                    block()
                    currentDelay = initialDelay
                } catch (e: IOException) {
                    currentDelay = (currentDelay * factor).toLong().coerceAtMost(maxDelay)
                }
                delay(currentDelay)
                yield()
            } catch (e: CancellationException) {
                break
            }
        }
    }


    class MyDataModel : ViewModel() {
        val pollScope = CloseableCoroutineScope(SupervisorJob(parent = viewModelScope.coroutineContext[Job]) + Dispatchers.Main)

        private val pollJobs = CopyOnWriteArrayList<Job>()

        inner class CloseableCoroutineScope(context: CoroutineContext) : FullLifecycleObserverAdapter(), CoroutineScope {
            override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext = context

            override fun onPause(owner: LifecycleOwner) {
                super.onPause(owner)
                // coroutineContext.cancel() cancels it but then coroutine doesn't start again in onResume() thats why cancelling jobs instead
                pollJobs.forEach { it.cancel() }
            }

            override fun onResume(owner: LifecycleOwner) {
                super.onResume(owner)
                refresh()
            }
        }

        fun refresh() {
            if (pollJobs.count { it.isActive } == 0) {
                startPoll()
            }
        }

        private fun startPoll() = pollScope.launch {
            try {
                poll {
                    //fetch data from server
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                //ignore
            }
        }.also {
            track(it)
        }

        private fun track(job: Job) {
            pollJobs.add(job)
            job.invokeOnCompletion {
                pollJobs.remove(job)
            }
        }
    }
```

Then in my fragment I add pollScope as lifecycle observer `viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycle.addObserver(viewModel.pollScope)`.

Comment: I don't think Kotlin coroutines is what you're looking for

Comment: I think Kotlin coroutines is something he could definitely use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Your `pollScope` seems fine to me.
2. When you're cancelling a `Job`, it cancels all Coroutines of that `Job`.
3. I would use a `ViewModel` with a `CoroutineScope` and then poll from it. Making sure to manage my `Job` and cancel my Coroutines when the VM dies.

```
class MyViewModel() : ViewModel(),
CoroutineScope by CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main + SupervisorJob()) {
    // ...
    override fun onCleared() {
        cancel()
        super.onCleared()
    }
}
```